# Qlik Sense - COUNT Measure with multiple logic/filter implementation

Tags: count, logic, minimax, measure, qliksense

I having an issue with measure setting logic as measure is validating but number are incorrect ,however when I deep dived the  measure it logically wrong, How I figured is by row numbers,

Measure 1 - Count( {<[Priority]={'1 - Critical','2 - High','3 - Moderate'}>} Incident_Number) = rows 255 (just all of the data in general)

Measure 2 - (Num(Count({<FYear_Num={$(=Max(FYear_Num))}>} Incident_Number), '##.00')) = rows 19583 (With a single Financial Year included)

However, below measure is Logically wrong

Measure 3 - (Num(Count({<FYear_Num={$(=Max(FYear_Num))}> +<[Priority]={'1 - Critical','2 - High','3 - Moderate'}>} Incident_Number), '##.00')) - rows 19,763 (Combining of Measure 1 and 2 not sure)

why I am saying that is that number should be Below<255 for just 1 Financial year

But I am getting as per Measure 3 = 19,763

Clearly the issue is with Measure 3 but i dont get how its wrong.

**How do I combine Measure 1 and 2 correctly ?**Anyone cal help would be really appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer myself Anyone who is curious ,

(Num(Count({<FYear_Num={$(=Max(FYear_Num))},[Priority]={'1 - Critical','2 - High','3 - Moderate'}>} Incident_Number), '##.00')/(date(today(),'DD/MM/YYYY')-'01/10/2019'))/
(Num(Count({<FYear_Num={$(=Max(FYear_Num)-1)},[Priority]={'1 - Critical','2 - High','3 - Moderate'}>} Incident_Number), '##.00')/365)-1